# I want to set the date, but I couldn't, how can I do it?

Tags: c#, datetime

I don't want to get the last minutes and seconds of the date option. How can I do this?

My code:

```
string storeShort = "IDEA" + orderItem.id + 'T' + DateTime.Parse(orderItem.createdAt, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

It comes like this: IDEA8T30.03.2021 14:55:11
I want like this: IDEA8T30.03.2021
I don't want to get the last part here ie hours minutes and seconds.How can I modify my code here accordingly?

Comment: Use the `ToString` function to apply a different format to the result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick can be done using `ToString`. The code should look like this:

```
var someDateTime = DateTime
    .Parse(orderItem.createdAt, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

string storeShort = "IDEA" + orderItem.id + 'T' + someDateTime;
// OR nicer:
var storeShort = $"IDEA{orderItem.id}T{someDateTime}";
```

The possible formatting options can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0).

Comment: `mm` stands for minute (with leading zero). Use `MM` instead for months.

Answer (score -1):

You could try simply adding ".Date" at the end of the parse to ignore the "time" part, like this :

```
string storeShort = "IDEA" + orderItem.id + 'T' +
    DateTime.Parse(orderItem.createdAt, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Date;
```

#### Important:

You can never know how the data will look like on different systems, because of the potential different culters on different systems.

Comment: The problem in this approach is that he is using `CurrentCultuer`, which means, you can never know how the data will look like on different systems.

Comment: I was supposing that he was okay with how the date was displaying and only answering to the "how to remove the time part" question. 
To have full control over how the datetime is parsed I'm totally okay with the toString approach.